# Does moving a where clause to the join clause improve performance?

Tags: mysql

I have a slow-running update statement, and I was curious if moving the where condition to the join clause would improve performance. Here's the query:

```
update T1 inner join (select ID, GROUP_CONCAT(x) as X from T3 group by ID) as T2

on T1.ID=T2.ID set T1.X=T2.X where T1.TYPE='something';
```

Now... for a very big table (millions of records), would it be faster to do this?

```
update T1 inner join (select ID, GROUP_CONCAT(x) as X from T3 group by ID) as T2

on T1.ID=T2.ID and T1.TYPE='something' set T1.X=T2.X;
```

Comment: What percentage of rows in T1 have TYPE = 'something'? Is the fraction of corresponding rows in T2 the same? How many rows are there typically in T2 for each row in T1?

Answer (score 0):

The query is simple enough that both approaches should be optimized identically.

Both approaches might also be sub-optimal because the inner query isn't correlated to the outer query.  Your query is creating an implicit temporary table containing all possible rows for derived table T2 -- exactly the same result as if you just ran the query `select ID, GROUP_CONCAT(x) as X from T3 group by ID` by itself -- and then the server is discarding the ones that can't be joined to T1 and using the rest to do the update.

This is more than likely not the optimum path.

Unless t1.TYPE = 'something' involves a large percentage of the rows in T1, it should be more efficient to do this:

```
UPDATE t1
   SET t1.x = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(x) FROM T3 WHERE T3.id = T1.id GROUP BY T3.id)
 WHERE t1.TYPE = 'something';
```

The inner subquery is correlated to the outer subquery, and only executed for the rows in T1 that are matched by the `WHERE` clause.